# I am Muslim but my Step-son is Christian and he eats Bacon and Ham (Pork)

Tags: halal-haram, food, pork

I am Muslim but my Step-son is Christian and he eats Bacon and Ham (Pork). Since we live in the same house, Is it allowed to bring Bacon and Ham (Pork) in the house though I do not consume it? Is it permissible for me to buy such food for him with my Halal rizq when he ask for? please advise.

Answer (score -1):

No it is haram

Because when Allah makes some things haram Allah make it haram even to buy.

https://youtu.be/H04huVRlV3g

I know it is taking about cats but you can understand it.

So basically he is saying it is haram to buy non halal food.

Comment: He's not buying the pork for himself though, doesn't it matter at all?

Comment: @SpiderRico You can see the video, even thou it is for cat but the question is almost the same. You can understand it with context

Answer (score -3):

No it is not Haram you have to understand that For Christians all foods are clean, early on when The followers of Jesus were preaching the Gospel Peter in the book of acts saw a vision where God told him to eat the types of foods that Jews Consider unclean Peter said to God " I surely cannot eat what is unclean" God then said do not call unclean what God has made clean.

Comment: Additional For Christians beleive that what enters the mouth of a man is not which defiles him but what comes out of a man. For in the heart are all types of sin